# Como definir um valor booleano de um RadioGroup

Tags: android, radiobutton

Exemplo:

```
EditText etNome      =  (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etName);
EditText etAge       =  (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAge);
RadioGroup rgClienteVivo = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rgClienteVivo);
```

Se eu quisesse setar esse dois valores seria assim:

```
usuario.setNome(etNome.getText().toString());
usuario.setAge(etAge.getText().toString());
```

Como ficaria o do `RadioGroup`?

Answer (score 1):

O [RadioGroup](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.html) gere um conjunto de [RadioButton](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioButton.html) em que, quando um é seleccionado, desselecciona o previamente seleccionado.

É possível seleccionar qualquer um dos *RadioButton* dentro do *RadioGroup* de duas formas:

- através do `R.id` do botão

  ```
  mRadioGroup.check(R.id.radioButton1);
  ```
- através da posição(índice) que ele ocupa no *RadioGroup*

  ```
  RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton)mRadioGroup.getChildAt(indice);
  radioButton.setChecked(true);
  ```

Para desseleccionar todos o botões use:

```
mRadioGroup.clearCheck();
```

Para obter o `R.id` do botão seleccionado use:

```
int id = mRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
```

Para executar determinado código em função do botão seleccionado use:

```
int id = mRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

switch(id){

    case R.id.radioButton1:
        ...
        ...
    break;
    case R.id.radioButton2:
        ...
        ...
    break;
}
```